# How can I make inference in CompuBERT?

Tags: machine-learning

My question is about the paper [Three is Better than One Ensembling Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2696/paper_235.pdf) (a system used for math information retrieval - both for finding answers and formula search)(code on [github](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT)).

Before the questions, the following figures illustrates:

CompuBERT (taken from [Three is Better than One Ensembling Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2696/paper_235.pdf)).

sentence-BERT (taken from [Sentence-BERT Sentence Embeddings using Siamese BERT-Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.10084.pdf)).

[image]

CompuBERT uses sentence-BERT but the paper [Three is Better than One Ensembling Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2696/paper_235.pdf) does not explain the inferece (question answering) step. (the inference step in sentence-BERT is illustrated at the bottom left on the picture)

How can I make inferece with CompuBERT?

(please explain using the implementation on [github](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT))

Answer (score 3):

CompuBERT's objective is to create representations, i.e. embeddings $E$ such that a distance of a question to a relevant answer is minimal, while its distance to an irrelevant question is maximal.

On indexing (see in [code](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT/blob/c535ff13d954ce718b20a95e4499d68d1cd32d61/question_answer/sbert_ir_system.py#L59)), you infer these embeddings $Ea_{1,..,n}$ for every potential answer in the collection.

On inference (see in [code](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT/blob/c535ff13d954ce718b20a95e4499d68d1cd32d61/question_answer/sbert_ir_system.py#L101)), you first infer an embedding $Eq$ of the asked question. Then, the embeddings of the relevant answers to this question will be the ones having the closest embeddings in your indexed collection. Hence, you search for the answers with minimal distance $\text{dist}(Eq, Ea_i)$.

As shown in Fig. 7, CompuBERT is fine-tuned to optimize $\text{dist}(Eq, Ea_i)=\cos(Eq, Ea_i)$, so using a cosine distance might be a good choice of distance a function. Authors of [Sentence-BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084) report good performance for other distance metrics as well, depending on the use-case.

Note that by the time, we've extended our research further and found out that for this specific task, better objectives than *Cosine Similarity Loss* can be found, such as *[Multiple Negatives Ranking Loss](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/tree/c3ffe418a4f434d7eadc18f30408cf1970bba642/examples/training/quora_duplicate_questions#multiplenegativesrankingloss)*. A paper with the results, together with a simplified implementation will be published soon in the following weeks.